# Why delegated constructor doesn't work as expected UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am having issues with loading the asset for several weapons in the game, such as AK 47, M11, and so on, the issue here is that I created a c++ class for doing that work which will be

```
    header
    
    UCLASS()
    AWeapon_core : public AActor
    {
        private: 
        USkeletalMeshComponent* m_skeletal_mesh;

        public:
        AWeapon_core(FString);
    
        protected:
        const FString mk_default_path;  
    };
    
    cpp
    
    AWeapon_core::AWeapon_core(FString _path)
    {
        m_skeletal_mesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<USkeletalMeshComponent>(TEXT("Weapon_mesh"));
    static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<USkeletalMesh> WEAPON_MESH(*(mk_weapon_mesh_path + _path));

    if (WEAPON_MESH.Succeeded())
        m_skeletal_mesh->SetSkeletalMesh(WEAPON_MESH.Object);
    }
```

And for the weapons, for example AK-47

```
    header

class AAK47 : public AWeapon_core
{
    public:
    AAK47();
}

cpp

AAK47::AAK47() : AWeapon_core("The path of the AK47 mesh file")
{
}
```

Did the same for all of the others weapons but it creates with the same mesh, what could be wrong here?

Comment: yes, AWeapon_core has the meshcomponent, and it loads the mesh based on what received from delegate constructor parameter

Comment: Ok edited the cpp file for Weapon_core

Comment: Ok gotta check it

Comment: @Game_dev it's not that. your mesh  got only one instance.. whatever mesh you would load first  would be used in all derived objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you realize what you did here?

```
static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<USkeletalMesh> 
                       WEAPON_MESH(*(mk_weapon_mesh_path + _path));
```

It's a STATIC LOCAL variable. It is initialized once. Only once as there is only one instance of `AWeapon_core::AWeapon_core()` function. All subsequent call to this constructor would use already initialized value.

Comment: @Game_dev I would say, keep assets in separate factory so similar objects would share access to them. If that's possible, of course.